# Chrome Service Worker iOS Support

Tags: ios, google-chrome, service-worker

As Apple announced Service Worker support for iOS 11.3 a few months ago, I recently started trying to get a service worker to work on iOS. On Safari it works as expected, after vising the website, it works offline. However, when trying to use the same feature in Chrome, I had intermittent results. Specifically, the service worker would only work every other page refresh, with the original refresh after going offline being one of the ones **not** working.

I know that Chrome on iOS is built on a version of Safari, therefore I am confused about this behavior.

Is this due to incomplete support from Chrome iOS for Service Workers? Because it is Chrome on iOS, I'm not sure of any easy way to debug it either, so any other tips to help track down the problem would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Chrome for iOS do not support service workers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#browser_support) currently(as of Apr-2020) and also the "Add to home screen" option is not available, if you are interested in that. Any offline page loading that you are experiencing should be from regular browser cache.

[Here is an official documentation](https://webkit.org/blog/8090/workers-at-your-service/) from Apple's web-kit page.

> Update: **A previous version of this post stated the Service Worker API
>   is available in all applications using WKWebView**. At this time it is
>   only available in Safari, applications that use
>   SFSafariViewController, and web applications saved to your home
>   screen.

Notably, Chrome uses WKWebView as its browser engine in iOS, which don't have service worker support yet as per the above statement(which you can find in the link provided above). So the only way you can use Service worker in iOS is to use Safari browser or use one of the above supported web-views inside a native app.

[Here is an article](https://www.monterail.com/blog/pwa-for-apple-ios) on what all PWA features iOS is still missing. Remember, this is a fast growing area. Always check if what is applicable now, especially if the documentation/article is getting older.

[Here is an adapter](https://github.com/RemoteDebug/remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter) to help debug in Chrome dev tools for pages loaded iOS - webkit/safari. Hope it becomes as easy as Android Chrome debugging one day!

Comment: I have revived an issue from 2017 on the GitHub repo for caniuse.com? I have offered to help clarify the information around browser support for ServiceWorkers. https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/3519 Give me a thumbs up or a comment if you support the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome for iOS is open source (https://blog.chromium.org/2017/01/open-sourcing-chrome-on-ios.html)
We can install the Chrome app with our developer signed certificate on an iOS device, launch the Chrome App, and start testing.

It is technically feasible.

Answer (score 0):

As an update in January 2021: the [official documentation from Apple's web-kit page](https://webkit.org/blog/8090/workers-at-your-service/) still says the same thing, and I just battled a very difficult to debug issue in Chrome iOS - posting here in case it helps someone.

I had an iFrame containing a cross-origin Angular 10 PWA with Service Worker enabled, and the iFrame content would not show after an initial load - no errors, no server logs, just blank. The only solution that worked was to self-destruct the Service Worker [per Angular's docs](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#safety-worker), and now the iFrame loads fine.