# Add to homescreen prompt not being shown in IOS with Angular

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I followed the instruction on https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started on how to build PWA Apps.

All is working in Android app, the prompt is showing and all. However, When I tried it on my ios the prompt is not showing at all (google and safari).

I really don't know where to start fixing.

Thanks!

Comment: ..we are missing your IOS version and your code

Comment: The code is generated by angular cli. The IOS version is > 12.

Comment: There is no automatic prompt for add to homescreen on iOS. You will have to trigger this yourself.

Comment: @ChrisLove How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS doesn't support web install banners/prompt yet.. in any browser.

Safari in iOS supports good part of PWA, including Service worker, Index DB. [But it has lots of limitation compared to Android.](https://www.monterail.com/blog/pwa-for-apple-ios) In iOS- Safari, user can go to menu and choose "add to home screen" and thats currently the only way user can do in iOS. You can show a full page instruction GIF requesting user to do the same. Unfortunately, thats the best we can do as a developer.

Chrome in iOS - [Doesn't support service worker itself.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50611655/1057093) So we cant even say it supports PWA in iOS.

Comment: No.. except for the scenario when u catch the install prompt event from the browser and use that for once and you are done with it. To get another install event may take several weeks of users continuous use.